# Python: "If" function

Tags: python, list, if-statement, range

This is probably really simple but I can't figure it out.

I have a bunch of lists and I want to call certain lists if they are in the range equal to a value x and any number between x-5 and x +5. i.e. x-5,x-4,x-3,x-2,x-1,x,x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4 and x+5.

At the moment I have

```
if sum(listname[i])==x:

if sum(listname[i])==x-1:

if sum(listname[i])==x-2:
```

etc

How can I do it so that it is combined in one "if" function.

I've been thinking on the lines of something like:

```
if sum(listname[i])==x-5>=x>=x+5:
```

or

```
if sum(listname[i])==x or x-1 or x-2 ".. etc":
```

but neither work.

Can anybody shine some light on this?

Comment: This is pretty theoretical, can you make a [MCVE] with complete sample input and output? Also, your terminology is a bit shaky. `if` is not a function and you can't call lists. (We should be able to understand what you want with the MCVE, though.)

Comment: Try this `if x-5 <= sum(listname[i]) <= x+5:`. If x is a real number x-5 cannot be superior to x+5

Answer (score 3):

A scenario like `if sum(listname[i])==x or x-1 or x-2 ".. etc":` (which is not valid python) is usually solved with `if value in range(start, stop, step):`

So you would write:

```
if sum(listname[i) in range(x-2, x):
    # Code for this case here...
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you simply mean

```
if x-5 <= sum(listname[i]) <= x+5:
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: You might want to exchange `>=` with `<=`. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: x-5 cannot be superior to x+5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to check if the sum of the list is between `x - 5` and `x + 5`. To put it in one if statement is simply:

```
s = sum(listname[i])
if s >= x - 5 and s <= x + 5:
  # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question. You what to check that whether `sum(listname[i])` is between `(x-5, x+5)`

You can do this in a single if assuming x is a possitive value:

```py
if (sum(listname[i]) >= (x - 5)) and (sum(listname[i]) <= (x+5))
```